# How is this screw head called?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

I want to disassemble a broken hair dryer (just to see what's inside), but I just found out it uses a weird tamper-proof screw I had never seen in my life. Trying to google for it doesn't help much; I still could not find its official name.

It's like a standard flat screw, where the central part has not been cut, and looks like this from above:

[image: unnamed screw head]

It looks a bit like an "H", so I tried looking for "H screw" and got a [few](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dy9c.jpg) Google [hits](http://image.made-in-china.com/4f0j00LMkEDIHRqhcp/H-Head-Self-Drilling-Screw.jpg), but I find very few of them, and they look mostly related to watches.

I find it appalling that Philips (the hair dryer manufacturer) needs to put such tamper-proof protection on such a common household appliance, but I suppose they have their legal reasons to do so. However, without knowing the name of the screw, I can hardly find where to buy a screwdriver for it!

If there is an official name for this screw, please enlighten me. I found a [screwdriver photo](http://i1080.photobucket.com/albums/j329/ALE7575/HUBLOT%20HBB%20V6/SCREWDRIVERPURETIME.jpg) on the Internet, but it seems to be small and related to watches. My screw is a "standard small appliance size".

Comment: I would use an old flat-head screwdriver and my Dremel with a thin, flat metal grinding disk to cut the screwdriver blade to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known as a Spanner Screw. It sometimes is slots, other times two small holes.